# How to generate a proxy class in .NET using a WSDL file

Tags: .net, proxy, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I was trying to create a proxy class for a WSDL file having the below target namespace:

> NameSpace: http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2006/08/wdp/scan

I'm getting the following error when i use the svcutil tool:

> Unable to bind port type 'CreateScanJobRequest'

Comment: Have you tried the [WSDL CLI tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an existing issue of .Net 4.0

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/468993/svcutil-exe-unable-to-match-binding-and-porttype-operations

OR

it could be requiring a name to the tag as mentioned in Bad-ish WSDL Section in the below link

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BreakingAllTheRulesWithWCF.aspx